# How to make Print() method memory & CPU efficient?

Tags: algorithm, go

## Problem Statement

You are receiving n objects in a random order, and you need to print them to stdout correctly ordered by sequence number.

The sequence numbers start from 0 (zero) and you have to wait until you get a complete, unbroken sequence batch of j objects before you output them.

You have to process all objects without loss. The program should exit once it completes outputting the first 50000 objects Batch size j = 100

The object is defined as such:

```
    {
    "id" : "object_id", // object ID (string)
    "seq" : 0, // object sequence number (int64, 0-49999)
    "data" : "" // []bytes
    }
```

## Example Output Statement

```
    Step                Input Value                Output State j = 1                  Output state j = 3
    0                       6
    1                       0                           0
    2                       4                           0
    3                       2                           0
    4                       1                           0,1,2                               0,1,2
    5                       3                           0,1,2,3,4                           0,1,2
    6                       9                           0,1,2,3,4                           0,1,2
    7                       5                           0,1,2,3,4,5,6                       0,1,2,3,4,5
```

---

## Solution

```
func (receiver *Receiver) Print(seqNumber uint64, batchSize uint64, outputFile io.Writer) (error, bool) {

    fmt.Fprintf(outputFile, "[ ")
    if seqNumber >= receiver.outputSequence.length {
        receiver.outputSequence.bufferSizeIncrease(seqNumber)
    }
    receiver.outputSequence.sequence[seqNumber] = true

    printedCount := uint64(0) // check for MAX_OBJECTS_TO_PRINT
    var nthBatchStartingIndex uint64
    MaxObjectsToPrint := config.GetMaxPrintSize()
Loop:
    for nthBatchStartingIndex < receiver.outputSequence.length { // check unbroken sequence
        var assessIndex = nthBatchStartingIndex
        for j := assessIndex; j < nthBatchStartingIndex+batchSize; j++ { // Assess nth batch
            if j >= receiver.outputSequence.length { //index out of range - edge case
                break Loop
            }
            if receiver.outputSequence.sequence[j] == false {
                break Loop
            }
        }

        count, printThresholdReached := receiver.printAssessedBatchIndexes(assessIndex, printedCount, batchSize, MaxObjectsToPrint, outputFile)
        if printThresholdReached { // print sequence threshold reached MAX_OBJECTS_TO_PRINT
            fmt.Fprintf(outputFile, " ]  ")
            fmt.Fprintf(outputFile, " ----for input value %d\n", seqNumber)
            return nil, false
        }
        printedCount += count
        if printedCount >= MaxObjectsToPrint { // print sequence threshold reached MAX_OBJECTS_TO_PRINT
            fmt.Fprintf(outputFile, " ]  ")
            fmt.Fprintf(outputFile, " ----for input value %d\n", seqNumber)
            receiver.Log.Printf("****MaxObjectsToPrint threshold(%d) reached \n", MaxObjectsToPrint)
            return nil, false
        }
        nthBatchStartingIndex = assessIndex + batchSize // next batch
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(outputFile, " ]  ")
    fmt.Fprintf(outputFile, " ----for input value %d\n", seqNumber)
    return nil, true
}
```

---

[Here](https://github.com/shamhub/threadapp) is the complete solution, written for this problem.

---

`Print()` is the method that does heavy lifting in this code, with varying size of memory & heavy CPU usage:

1. How to make `receiver.outputSequence` memory effective by using datastructure other than array? because `newBufferSize := 2 * seqNumber` is doubling memory...
2. How to make `Print` method have effective CPU usage? On some goroutine

Comment: What does "batch size j=100" mean? Does it mean you will never receive out-of-sequence entries farther than 100? If so, you can do this with a fixed size array of 100. If that's not the case, you might want to try putting the elements in a map instead of an array. No matter the solution, you have to remember max(distance between out of sequence elements). With a slice, you have to move them as well.

Comment: @BurakSerdar batch size j = 3 mean {0,1,2} {3,4,5}....batch size j = 2 mean {0,1} {2,3} {4,5}... So, batch size j=100 mean, once we have 100 unbroken sequence {0.1.2.3.4.5,.....99} then display it

Comment: @BurakSerdar batch size j = 3 mean display unbroken sequence of set of 3 elements {0,1,2} {3,4,5}....batch size j = 2 mean display unbroken sequence of set of 2 elements {0,1} {2,3} {4,5}... So, batch size j=100 mean, once we have 100 unbroken sequence {0.1.2.3.4.5,.....99} then display it

Comment: I think you overcomplicated the problem by trying to keep things in a slice. If the seqnumber is int and no seqnumbers are skipped, you can simply keep a map keyed with seqnumber and the last item printed. Then when you get the next item in sequence, output the next items until you hit a gap. If you need to batch the output, you can batch it up after this stage.

Comment: @BurakSerdar sequence numbers are coming in random order. For me linkedlist makes more sense, because ordering is enforced

Comment: Linked list will have the worst time complexity because the only way to find elements in it is using linear search. A map definitely outperforms a linked list in this scenario. It is likely to outperform a slice as well.

Comment: @BurakSerdar  So, what would be the map key and its value?

Comment: Map key would be the sequence (int) and value be the struct. You keep the last sequence printed in a variable, and when you get the next in sequence, you print the following items from the map until you hit the next gap.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Why do we need map, when we already have variable holding the printed sequence? map is not sorted as well. Is the value struct an empty struct? can you post the code in an answer?

Comment: No. You put the object you receive into the map, using the sequence as the key. You don't have a variable holding the sequence, you only have a variable holding the last printed sequence value (a single int). When you receive the next in sequence, you use map to lookup the objects you stored using the correct sequence. This way you only have to store minimal possible number of objects, you look them up with amortized-constant time, and you don't have to resize a slice.

Answer (score 3):

First, observe that if you receive an out-of-sequence object, you have to potentially keep all the objects from the latest printed sequence number to the received number. Worst case, you receive the object in reverse order and have to keep them all in memory. There is no way around this. So, what you can optimize is first, when you are printing objects you can find them quickly, and second, you don't want to move them around, which will happen if you use a slice and grow it as necessary.

So, a sketch of an algorithm that will use CPU and memory better than what you have is as follows:

```
var nextInSequence=0 // The next item you are expecting in the sequence
var storedObjects=map[int]SomeStruct{}

func Print(seqNumber int, obj SomeStruct) {
   if seqNumber==nextInSequence {
     output obj
     nextInSequence++
   } else {
      storedObjects[seqNumber]=obj
   }
   for {
     if stored, ok:=storedObjects[nextInSequence] ; ok {
        output stored
        delete(storedObjects,nextInSequence)
        nextInSequence ++
     } else {
        break
     }
  }
}
```